# Can moderators see deleted comments?

Tags: support, comments, moderation

A comment can be made obsolete, for instance, by the deletion of an earlier comment on the same post.

Under the assumption that a comment on a given post (question or answer) gets flagged as obsolete and that flag gets reviewed by a moderator, I can imagine how the moderator could be unsure as to what to do (delete the comment or reject the flag) if s/he not have access to the whole history of comments on that post.

Hence my question: do moderators have access to deleted comments?

Comment: Unless some community user flags useless comment, _I_ think it's not moderators job in a look to delete comments and cleanup, this job depends on a responsible community User mostly to delete his own and flag obsolete ones. Related [Should we clean up obsolete comments?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1477/15717)

Comment: @texenthusiast I wasn't suggesting that moderators should scour the site for obsolete comments. See my edit.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, moderators can choose to see deleted comments and flag history (including 'handled' flags). So we can see the context of flags or later comments.